# What does $\sum\frac {1-\sin n} {n\sqrt{n}}$ converge to?

Tags: real-analysis

What does $\sum\frac {1-\sin n} {n\sqrt{n}}$ converge to?

From squeeze theorem:

$$0 \leq \frac {1- \sin {n}} {n\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac { 2 } {n\sqrt{n}}$$

And I want to know how to show $\frac{2}{n\sqrt{n}}$ coverge to $0$

So what does it converge to?

Comment: If you're asking whether it converges, then the answer is yes.  You have shown that the summand is bounded in absolute value by $\frac2{n^{3/2}}$.  If you are asking for a closed form solution, then none exists in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Using squeeze $ \frac { 1- \sin {n} } { (n)(\sqrt{n})} \rightarrow 0$ because $\frac{2}{ (n)(\sqrt{n})} \rightarrow 0$ .. but how is this going to help you evaluate your sum ?

Comment: I want to know how to show $\frac {2} {n^3/2}$  converge to 0

Comment: It is true that the terms of the summation go to $0$, but the sum itself does not.

Comment: As noted, above $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} n} \neq 0$ and therefore [$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \sin(n)}{\sqrt{n} n} \neq 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+(1-sin(n))%2F(sqrt(n)+*n)+from+n+%3D+1+to+infty)

Answer (score 1):

This question, though you might not know it, is actually just the Riemann zeta function. The summation is always less than $\sum\frac{2}{n\sqrt{n}}$. This is 2 times $\sum\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$, which is the definition of $\zeta(\frac{3}{2})$, which is finite, and approximately 2.61237534868548834335. Thus, your summation is always between 0 and about 5.225, so it is convergent. To answer your question, there is no simple closed form for the summation. If you want an approximation, 1.56181650155768672226529827471.